# Nginx is ignoring www in my rules while I don't want to

Tags: nginx

**What I want:**

I want to redirect www.mydomain.eu and mydomain.eu to, let's say, www.google.com, while having access to a local gitea server through git.mydomain.eu.

**What I have:**

I have this nginx config in /etc/nginx/sites-available:

```
ssl_certificate /XXX/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /XXX/privkey.pem;

server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name www.mydomain.eu mydomain.eu;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location / {
                return 301 http://google.com;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name git.mydomain.eu;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
}
```

with XXX being an absolute location and mydomain being the actual name of my domain (this config file is also in sites-enabled thanks to a "ln -s" command)

**What my problem is**

When I go to https://mydomain.eu, I am redirected to https://www.google.com/. => great !

When I go to https://**www**.mydomain.eu, Firefox (and chrome) says that "This site can’t be reached" => :(, different behavior than mydomain.eu, why ?

Same with https://**git**.mydomain.eu ("This site can’t be reached") => why ? I am sure that http://localhost:3000 is a valid website, as I can access it through its IP address.

It seems that nginx ignores the "www" in my first rule, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: What is your CNAME settings on your domain host?

Comment: For example, in order to be able to access `git.example.com`, you will need to have a CNAME configured at your host with CNAME host as `git`, and value as `example.com`. You also need another one for `www`.

Comment: You are completely right, I needed to add this CNAME... Thank you very much ! This problem is solved ! Can you write a response, so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to nginx but your domain host configuration as the net traffic not even reach to your nginx server yet.

In order to be able to access `git.example.com`, you will need to have a CNAME configured at your host with CNAME host as `git`, and value as `example.com`. You also need another one for `www`, as shown below:

```
Type          Host        Value
CNAME         git         example.com
CNAME         www         example.com
```

One more thing to be aware is if you are using a sub-domain like `git.example.com`, depend on how you configure your ssl certificate and what kind of ssl certificate you purchased, the `git.example.com` may need a separate ssl certificate, unless you have a multi-site ssl certificate....